# API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner

Tags: python, api, salesforce, integration, odoo

How to enable the API for salesforce ? Currently I am getting error like   *"API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner"*.  I am using python sdk and using trial version of salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API is an 'add on' feature for Professional Edition.  You will not be able to enable that during your trial.

If you want to experiment with Connected Apps, you can sign up for a free Developer Edition at https://developer.salesforce.com.  This will be an Enterprise Edition org (with small data allowance).